# JavaFX Default Implementation of Closing Windows

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, dialog

I'd like to know what exactly happens when the red cross is pressed in dialog widows.

I have a dialog which adds data to a dynamic `LineChart` and updates the chart with the new point. The problem is that when I close the dialog **programmatically** after the adding job, the UI doesn't update properly. But if I don't close it programmatically and just press the **default** cross button, everything is OK.

My closing code was the following line which never updated the UI properly:

```
((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

and when I use `Platform.runLater()` to do so, it sometimes updates and sometimes not!

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                }
            });
```

BTW, if you want to see how the updating job goes, here it is:

I have a dialog which is defined in a fxml file and has two textfields for getting x and y and also an **Add** button. This **Add** button has an `onAction` method called `handleAddButton()` which is defined in the `DialogController` class. Then in this method, I call the `addData()` method from the `LineChartController` Class as below:

```
public void handleAddButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    Number x = new NumberStringConverter().fromString(timeField.getText());
    Number y = new NumberStringConverter().fromString(bandWidthField.getText());

    lineChartController.addData(x, y);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((Button)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }
        });
}
```

And  This is the `addData()` method implementation in the `LineChartController` class:

```
public void addData(Number xValue, Number yValue){

        if(xValue.intValue() < 0 || xValue.intValue() > 3000 ||
                yValue.intValue() < 0 || yValue.intValue() > 1000)
            return;
        XYChart.Data<Number , Number> data =
                new XYChart.Data<>(SystemUtil.round(xValue.intValue()), SystemUtil.round(yValue.intValue()));
        seri.getData().add(data);

        Node currentNode = data.getNode();
        currentNode.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        currentNode.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            Point2D pointInScene = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            double xPosInAxis = timeAxis.sceneToLocal(new Point2D(pointInScene.getX(), 0)).getX();
            double yPosInAxis = bandWidthAxis.sceneToLocal(new Point2D(0, pointInScene.getY())).getY();
            int x = timeAxis.getValueForDisplay(xPosInAxis).intValue();
            int y = bandWidthAxis.getValueForDisplay(yPosInAxis).intValue();
            data.setXValue(SystemUtil.round(x));
            data.setYValue(SystemUtil.round(y));
        });
        currentNode.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {

            if(chartContextMenu.isShowing())
                chartContextMenu.hide();
            dataContextMenu.setUserData(data);
            dataContextMenu.show(lineChart1, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
        });
    }
```

**I wish I could know what exactly the default closing does, which keeps everything OK and what's wrong with my code.**

Comment: How are you retrieving x , y from dialog?

Comment: @omid `Number x = new NumberStringConverter().fromString(timeField.getText());`

Comment: I don't think the problem is with addData method. Are x,y get retrieved correctly? Can you please add the code for dialog, how you show it and where you get x and y from it? Without that it's not possible to help you.

Comment: Where are you calling `lineChartController.addData(x, y);` from? An `onHidden` handler on the dialog? Can you show that code? Preferably, [edit] your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: The actual answer to the question you asked is that the "close button" is implemented natively: i.e. it is part of the operating system's rendering of the window. So effectively the event handler on it is provided by the native windowing toolkit. The entire mechanism here is very different to calling `close()` programmatically.

Comment: @Omid I don't think there's any problem with retrieving x and y. Cause it works well when I just comment out the closing code.

Comment: @James_D Yes, I call it from an `onAction` method. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I am still confused as to which code is where. I recommend you create and post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. It seems that the native close button somehow puts a delay before hiding the dialog and lets the background operation do the job properly.

So now, by only putting this **sleep time** at the end of the `addData()` method, everything is OK:

```
 try {
      Thread.sleep(30);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

It's clear that adding this part in the `handleAddButton()` method and just before the closing code, also works. But cause I call the `addData()` from many places, I preferred to put it there.

Comment: I seriously don't understand how this can happen if all of these are running on the application thread. `addData()` is supposed to complete its execution before `hide()` is reached and executed.

Comment: Your "workaround" points to a threading issue - so there's probably a bug somewhere else in your code. If you posted a [mcve] like @James_D recommended, it would be possible to help you more.

Comment: This is nonsense. How can you be assured 30 milliseconds is always going to be enough? You have something fundamentally wrong in the code you are not showing us: the solution is to fix that, not to use some arbitrary hack like this.

Comment: @James_D I found  this 30 ms with trial and error and now I'm quite sure that it will always work. AFAIK there's no uncertainty in adding data. And I really don't know where else to post. The project is too large.

Comment: @assylias As I said, in my view the post is minimal, complete, and verifiable. I've no idea which other part of my big project is related.

Comment: @ZahraEzati You should really read the link in my comment. Complete means that I can copy/paste your code, compile it and run it. Verifiable means that when doing so, I can observe the behaviour you describe (and minimal means that you don't have to post your whole project). At the moment, the code you have posted lacks a few variable declarations and doesn't have a "main", so people can only do guess work, which is generally not productive for you.

Comment: And as said above, there is a very high chance that the bug that causes the issue will hit you back at some point (because you run the program on another computer or because the JDK has been updated or because a number of reasons not under your control).